# Date count for Intersection of 2 date ranges

Tags: mysql

I want to get the number of date(s) intersected between two date ranges. For example if one date range is 01/11/2014 - 25/11/2014 and second date range is 25/10/2014 - 10/11/2014 and the intersected date number is 10(01/11/2014 - 10/11/2104).How can i write a mysql query to get the result. My table structure is 
                     records(sfid int, date1 date, date2 date).

I want to input one date range and want to get sfid and the intersected date number for the corresponding input date range.

Comment: Can you share your tables' structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table (event_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,start_date DATE,end_date DATE);

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,'2014-10-25','2014-11-10'),(2,'2014-11-01','2014-11-25');

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----------+------------+------------+
 | event_id | start_date | end_date   |
 +----------+------------+------------+
 |        1 | 2014-10-25 | 2014-11-10 |
 |        2 | 2014-11-01 | 2014-11-25 |
 +----------+------------+------------+

 SELECT GREATEST(x.start_date,y.start_date) start
      , LEAST(x.end_date,y.end_date) end
      , DATEDIFF(LEAST(x.end_date,y.end_date),GREATEST(x.start_date,y.start_date)) diff 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.event_id > x.event_id 
    AND y.start_date < x.end_date 
    AND y.end_date > x.start_date;
 +------------+------------+------+
 | start      | end        | diff |
 +------------+------------+------+
 | 2014-11-01 | 2014-11-10 |    9 |
 +------------+------------+------+
```

... or something like that.

Comment: Thank you Strawberry for the answer. It gave the correct result. Thanks once again.